# Eclipse CDT and LLVM with clang

Tags: macos, gcc, llvm, eclipse-cdt, clang

I installed llvm4eclipsecdt on my Macbook. Every time I create a new C++-Projekt with LLVM (clang) as build environment, I get an error message from gcc(?).

```
llvm-ld -v -native -o test main.bc
Linking bitcode file 'main.bc'
 Linked in file 'main.bc'
Generating Bitcode To test.bc
Generating Assembly With: 
'/usr/bin/llc' '-x86-asm-syntax=att' '-o' 'test.s' 'test.bc' 
Generating Native Executable With:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-strict-aliasing' '-O3' '-o' 'test' 'test.s' 
test.s:28:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_startproc
test.s:39:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_endproc
llvm-ld: 
Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

Why is llvm calling gcc? I can't find any settings about GCC in my project. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It calls `gcc` driver to produce object file from assembly. LLVM already has itegrated assembler for this, so i suppose that `llvm4eclipsecdt` thing is just too old.

Comment: It does this because it uses llvm-ld. Anyway it seems way too broken, e.g. default llc's options might not satisfy the majority needs.